# numpy - find all pixels near a set of pixels

Tags: numpy, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have a `PIL.Image` object `input` of mode `'1'` (a black & white bitmap) and I would like to determine, for every pixel in the image, whether it's within `n` pixels (Euclidean distance - `n` may be around 100 or so) of any of the white pixels.

The motivation is: `input` represents every pixel that is different between two other images, and I would like to create a highlight region around all those differences to show clearly where the differences occur.

So far I haven't been able to find a fast algorithm for this - the following code works, but the convolution is very slow because the `kernel` argument is larger than the convolution can apparently handle efficiently:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

n = 100
y, x = np.ogrid[:2*n, :2*n]
kernel = (x-n)**2 + (y-n)**2 <= n**2

img = Image.open('input.png')
result = ndimage.convolve(np.array(img), kernel) != 0
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

Example input `input.png`:

[image]

Desired output `result.png` (there are also some undesired artifacts here that I assume come from over/underflow):

[image]

Even with these small images, the computation takes 30 seconds or so.
Can someone recommend a better procedure to compute this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please share representative input images and corresponding expected output images so folk can better visualise what you are looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, I added example input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`ndimage.convolve` use a very inefficient algorithm** to perform the convolution certainly running in `O(n m kn km)` where `(n,m)` is the shape of the image and `(kn, km)` is the shape of the kernel. You can **use an FFT** to do that much more efficiently in `O(n m log(n m))` time. Hopefully, scipy provide such a function. Here is an example of usage:

```py
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

n = 100
y, x = np.ogrid[:2*n, :2*n]
kernel = (x-n)**2 + (y-n)**2 <= n**2

img = Image.open('input.png')
result = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(img, kernel, mode='same') >= 1.0
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

This is **>500 times faster** on my machine and this also *fix the artefacts*. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jérôme!  I'm used to R, where the `convolve` function automatically uses FFT, it didn't occur to me that scipy's version didn't also do that.